# Why can't I change my skin?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft PE on my Kindle Fire, however, I cannot change my skin; It is staying on the default, Alex. Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this?

The version I'm running is MCPE 16.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Insure you have Minecraft PE 0.11.x+
2. Search "Skins for Minecraft" in the kindle App Store, and then click an app.
3. Install the app, and open it up.
4. Click the head of the skin that you like the best.
5. Click the "Download Skin" button.
6. Open up minecraft, and you will see that your skin has changed!

Source: [Wikihow](http://m.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Skin-in-Minecraft-PE)